# Start Store Apps - Universal Apps for windows phone 8.1 and windows 8.1 application

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to start Universal Apps for windows phone 8.1 and windows 8.1 and I have found that when I am creating a new project, under visual C# I don't have Store Apps.

[image]

What should I download so that I have Store Apps -> Universal Apps? Like in this picture:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I have VS 2013, but how could I know which version? When I go to extensions and updates, it suggests Update 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature requires Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC (or higher), confirmed here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/14/using-visual-studio-to-build-universal-xaml-apps.aspx

Update your copy of visual studio, and you will have the new options! To check what you are running, go to the "About" option in the "Help" menu.